# PHP textarea security

Tags: php, security, save, filter-var, filter-input

When user chooses his `username` I do the following:

```
if($_POST['username'] != "") {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
}
```

But how to work with textarea´s, there is no option working with `filter_var`/`filter_input`, so what security do I need to include?

> strip_tags
>
> htmlspecialchars
>
> htmlentities

You have any advices?

Greetings!

Comment: Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.

Comment: just have to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info yes?

Comment: no need to add the function above?

Answer (score 0):

In your case - since you want to strip any markup from the input....

```
$text = strip_tags($_POST['textarea']);

$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($text);

mysqli->query("INSERT INTO yourtable (content) VALUES ('$text')");
```

...but when you want to output it again to a browser - you STILL NEED TO escape it appropriately....

```
if ($result = $mysqli->use_result()) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "<div>" . nl2br(htmlentities($row['content'])) . "</div>";
    }
}
```